# Using BeautifulSoup to parse <tr> tags, having trouble extracting values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html which looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>some text</td>
  <td>some other text</td>
  <td>some <b>problematic</b> other <br /> text</td>
</tr>
```

and some python which tries to grab the value of the  tags and print each inner  value:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    print repr(row) # this prints the whole 'tr' element text just fine.
    for col in row.contents:
        print col.string
```

so the full  text prints the captured html correctly, but the 'col' prints None for the last element:

```
some text
some other text
None
```

I'm not familiar with BeatifulSoup or python for that matter, but it seems like the inner tags of the last element are causing parsing problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upgrade to BeautifulSoup version 4 and use [`.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print '\n'.join(row.stripped_strings)
```

In BeautifulSoup 3, you need to search for all contained text instead:

```
for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    print '\n'.join(el.strip() for row.findAll(text=True) if el.strip())
```